# How to set the overall background color behind the view in React-Native

Tags: javascript, ios, css, react-native

Is there a way to set the overall backgroundColor behind the view being rendered in React Native? For example if I style my view with `marginTop: 30` then there is a blank whitespace above the view. I'm wondering if there is a way to alter this background color?

```
renderStoriesListView() {
if (this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0) {
  return (
    <Loading>top stories</Loading>
  )
} else {
  return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 30, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
    <RefreshableListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderStory}
      loadData={this.loadTopStories}
      refreshDescription="Refreshing top stories"
      refreshingIndictatorComponent={<Refreshing />}  

    /></View>
  )
}
},
  render() {
return this.renderStoriesListView()
}
})
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
<View style={{marginTop: 30}}>
<RefreshableListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderStory}
  loadData={this.loadTopStories}
  refreshDescription="Refreshing top stories"
  refreshingIndictatorComponent={<Refreshing />}  

/></View></View>
```